# C Ring Buffer Shared Memory Semaphore ReadPointer WritePointer Not Right

Tags: c, ubuntu

I want to build a File Copier using Reader-Writer Synchronization Paradigm.
The Writer initializes the both of the Mutexes. The FullMutex is denoting how many Buffers are available to Write and the FreeMutex is denoting how many Buffers are available to Read.
The Writer waits when the Block is Full.
The WritePointer and ReadPointer is using the Ring Buffer. Therefore I have used Mod Operation.
The Block Size=M.
The Buffer Size=B.
There are N number of Buffers.
So, M=N*B.
The File Size=2M.
And therefore BufferCount is actually advancing File Pointer.
When all Bytes are written, I am issuing FileEnding=1.

The compilation commands are-

```
g++ Writer.c -o Writer -lpthread -lrt
g++ Reader.c -o Reader -lpthread -lrt
```

And in 2 different comand prompts are open and the commands are issued-

```
./Writer
./Reader
```

Now I do not know why are the ReadPointer and the WritePointer coming this way?

Here is the Writer.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(void){
    char FileName[128]="aaa.txt";
    struct MemData{
        sem_t FullMutex;
        sem_t FreeMutex;
        int ReadPointer;
        int WritePointer;
        int FileEnding;
        char Data[512000];//MEMORY BLOCK SIZE: 500 KB
    };
    int SD;
    struct MemData *M;
    int NumberOfBuffers=10;
    //int BufferSize=51200;//FILE BUFFER SIZE 50 KB
    int BufferSize=2;//EXPERIMENATION
    unsigned char Buf[BufferSize];
    int BufferCount=0;

    SD= shm_open("/program.shared", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, S_IREAD|S_IWRITE);
    if(SD< 0){
        printf("\nshm_open() error \n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    fchmod(SD, S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO);
    if(ftruncate(SD, sizeof(MemData))< 0){
        printf ("ftruncate() error \n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    M=(struct MemData*)mmap(NULL, sizeof(MemData), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, SD, 0);
    if(M== MAP_FAILED){
        printf("mmap() error");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }else{
        sem_init(&M->FullMutex, 1, 0);
        sem_init(&M->FreeMutex, 1, NumberOfBuffers);
        M->FileEnding=0;
        M->ReadPointer=0;
        M->WritePointer=0;
        memset(M->Data, '\0', strlen(M->Data));
    }

    FILE *FP= fopen(FileName, "rb");
    if(FP!= NULL){
        struct stat StatBuf;
        if(stat(FileName, &StatBuf)==-1){
            printf("failed to fstat %s\n", FileName);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        long long FileSize=StatBuf.st_size;
        printf("\nFile Size: %lld", FileSize);
        long long FilePosition=ftell(FP);
        FilePosition=ftell(FP);
        long long CopyableMemorySize=FileSize-FilePosition;
        printf("\nCopyable File Size: %lld", CopyableMemorySize);
        int NumberOfFileBuffers=CopyableMemorySize/BufferSize;
        printf("\nNumber Of File Buffers: %d\n", NumberOfFileBuffers);

        //WRITE
        while(1){
            sem_wait(&M->FreeMutex);
            fseek(FP, BufferCount*BufferSize, SEEK_SET);
            fread(Buf, sizeof(unsigned char), BufferSize, FP);
            int FreeMutexValue;
            sem_getvalue(&M->FreeMutex, &FreeMutexValue);
            int FullMutexValue;
            sem_getvalue(&M->FullMutex, &FullMutexValue);
            printf("\nMutexes-Free: %d and Full: %d", FreeMutexValue, FullMutexValue);
            printf("\nBuffer Writing: %d", BufferCount);
            memcpy(&M->Data[M->WritePointer*BufferSize], &Buf, sizeof(Buf)*sizeof(unsigned char));
            BufferCount++;
            M->WritePointer=(M->WritePointer+1)%NumberOfBuffers;
            if(BufferCount>=NumberOfFileBuffers && M->WritePointer==M->ReadPointer){
                M->FileEnding=1;
                break;
            }
            sem_post(&M->FullMutex);
        }
        fclose(FP);
    }
    //close(SD);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the Reader.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(void){
    char FileName[128]="bbb.txt";
    struct MemData{
        sem_t FullMutex;
        sem_t FreeMutex;
        int ReadPointer;
        int WritePointer;
        int FileEnding;
        char Data[512000];//MEMORY BLOCK SIZE: 500 KB
    };
    int SD;
    struct MemData *M;
    int NumberOfBuffers=10;
    //int BufferSize=51200;//FILE BUFFER SIZE 50 KB
    int BufferSize=2;//EXPERIMENATION
    unsigned char Buf[BufferSize];
    int BufferCount=0;
    SD= shm_open("/program.shared", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, S_IREAD|S_IWRITE);
    if(SD< 0){
        printf("\nshm_open() error \n"); 
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    M=(struct MemData*)mmap(NULL, sizeof(MemData), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, SD, 0);
    if(M== MAP_FAILED){
        printf("mmap() error");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    FILE *FP= fopen(FileName, "wb");
    if(FP!= NULL){

        //READ
        while(1){
            sem_wait(&M->FullMutex);
            int FreeMutexValue;
            sem_getvalue(&M->FreeMutex, &FreeMutexValue);
            int FullMutexValue;
            sem_getvalue(&M->FullMutex, &FullMutexValue);
            printf("\nMutexes-Free: %d and Full: %d", FreeMutexValue, FullMutexValue);
            printf("\nBuffer Writing: %d", BufferCount);
            printf("\nReadPointer: %d", M->ReadPointer);
            printf("\nWritePointer: %d", M->WritePointer);
            fseek(FP, BufferCount*BufferSize, SEEK_SET);
            fwrite(&M->Data[M->ReadPointer*BufferSize], sizeof(unsigned char), BufferSize, FP);
            BufferCount++;
            M->ReadPointer=(M->ReadPointer+1)%NumberOfBuffers;
            if(M->FileEnding){
                fclose(FP);
                break;
            }
            sem_post(&M->FreeMutex);
        }
    }
    munmap(M,sizeof(MemData));
    close(SD);
    return 0;
}
```

The Output for Writer.c is

```
File Size: 50
Copyable File Size: 50
Number Of File Buffers: 25

Mutexes-Free: 9 and Full: 0
Buffer Writing: 0
Mutexes-Free: 8 and Full: 1
Buffer Writing: 1
Mutexes-Free: 7 and Full: 2
Buffer Writing: 2
Mutexes-Free: 6 and Full: 3
Buffer Writing: 3
Mutexes-Free: 5 and Full: 4
Buffer Writing: 4
Mutexes-Free: 4 and Full: 5
Buffer Writing: 5
Mutexes-Free: 3 and Full: 6
Buffer Writing: 6
Mutexes-Free: 2 and Full: 7
Buffer Writing: 7
Mutexes-Free: 1 and Full: 8
Buffer Writing: 8
Mutexes-Free: 0 and Full: 9
Buffer Writing: 9
Mutexes-Free: 0 and Full: 8
Buffer Writing: 10
Mutexes-Free: 2 and Full: 6
Buffer Writing: 11
Mutexes-Free: 1 and Full: 7
Buffer Writing: 12
Mutexes-Free: 0 and Full: 8
Buffer Writing: 13
Mutexes-Free: 0 and Full: 8
Buffer Writing: 14
Mutexes-Free: 0 and Full: 8
Buffer Writing: 15
Mutexes-Free: 0 and Full: 8
Buffer Writing: 16
Mutexes-Free: 1 and Full: 7
Buffer Writing: 17
Mutexes-Free: 0 and Full: 8
Buffer Writing: 18
Mutexes-Free: 0 and Full: 8
Buffer Writing: 19
Mutexes-Free: 0 and Full: 8
Buffer Writing: 20
Mutexes-Free: 0 and Full: 8
Buffer Writing: 21
Mutexes-Free: 0 and Full: 8
Buffer Writing: 22
Mutexes-Free: 0 and Full: 8
Buffer Writing: 23
Mutexes-Free: 0 and Full: 8
Buffer Writing: 24
```

The Output of the Reader.c is

```
Mutexes-Free: 0 and Full: 9
Buffer Writing: 0
ReadPointer: 0
WritePointer: 0
Mutexes-Free: 1 and Full: 8
Buffer Writing: 1
ReadPointer: 1
WritePointer: 0
Mutexes-Free: 1 and Full: 8
Buffer Writing: 2
ReadPointer: 2
WritePointer: 1
Mutexes-Free: 2 and Full: 7
Buffer Writing: 3
ReadPointer: 3
WritePointer: 1
Mutexes-Free: 2 and Full: 6
Buffer Writing: 4
ReadPointer: 4
WritePointer: 2
Mutexes-Free: 1 and Full: 7
Buffer Writing: 5
ReadPointer: 5
WritePointer: 4
Mutexes-Free: 1 and Full: 8
Buffer Writing: 6
ReadPointer: 6
WritePointer: 5
Mutexes-Free: 1 and Full: 8
Buffer Writing: 7
ReadPointer: 7
WritePointer: 7
Mutexes-Free: 1 and Full: 8
Buffer Writing: 8
ReadPointer: 8
WritePointer: 7
Mutexes-Free: 1 and Full: 7
Buffer Writing: 9
ReadPointer: 9
WritePointer: 8
Mutexes-Free: 1 and Full: 8
Buffer Writing: 10
ReadPointer: 0
WritePointer: 9
Mutexes-Free: 1 and Full: 7
Buffer Writing: 11
ReadPointer: 1
WritePointer: 0
Mutexes-Free: 1 and Full: 8
Buffer Writing: 12
ReadPointer: 2
WritePointer: 1
Mutexes-Free: 1 and Full: 7
Buffer Writing: 13
ReadPointer: 3
WritePointer: 2
Mutexes-Free: 1 and Full: 8
Buffer Writing: 14
ReadPointer: 4
WritePointer: 3
Mutexes-Free: 1 and Full: 8
Buffer Writing: 15
ReadPointer: 5
WritePointer: 4
```

The input(aaa.txt) file contains these lines-

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

The output(bbb.txt) file contains these lines-

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
```

Comment: You have a fine question, but avoid asking multiple-variants of the same question. IIRC this is the second ask of a very similar question today. Let's see if we can get this one answered.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I'm a bit confused exactly what you mean by `"Now I do not know why are the ReadPointer and the WritePointer coming this way?"` What are `ReadPointer` and `WritePointer` doing or not doing that your expect them to not do or do? Are you referring to the output from the `reader` program where they shuffle `{0,0}, {1,0}, {2,1}, ...`?  Also -- a good read is Consider [5 Big Fat Reasons Why Mutexes Suck Big Time](https://accu.org/var/uploads/journals/Overload149.pdf) (2nd Article) You should also have `sizeof(struct MemData)` in your code instead of `sizeof(MemData)` in a couple of places.

Comment: Your use of `&Buf` is wrong in `memcpy`, it should be `memcpy(&M->Data[M->WritePointer*BufferSize], Buf, sizeof *Buf);` or better `memcpy(&M->Data[M->WritePointer*BufferSize], Buf, BufferSize);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of small problems and a misuse of a pointer, but even correcting those, your writer/reader will still not be consistent in the copying of the file `aaa.txt` to `bbb.txt`. Why? The mutex logic is subject to take varying paths as you read the file and write to the shared memory, and unwind from it.

Let's first look at the number of small correction needed. Unless you provide a `typedef`, you need to use `struct MemData` as the type with `sizeof`, or better use the pointer itself. Next, `strlen(M->Data)` is invalid and should be `sizeof (M->Data));` when used with:

```
    memset (M->Data, '\0', sizeof (M->Data));
```

Next, you have pointer problems using `&Buf` in:

```
memcpy(&M->Data[M->WritePointer*BufferSize], &Buf, sizeof(Buf)*sizeof(unsigned char));
```

`Buf` is already a pointer and `sizeof(unsigned char) == 1`. Further, if you later allocate for `Buf` instead of using the VLA `unsigned char Buf[BufferSize];`, `sizeof (Buf)` will be `sizeof (a_pointer)`. Better to use:

```
        memcpy (&M->Data[M->WritePointer*BufferSize], Buf, BufferSize);
```

In Writer.c after you get your `FileSize` with `StatBuf.st_size`, there is no reason to call `ftell (FP)` as you haven't moved the file-position indicator with `fseek` anywhere in that code. Likewise in Writer.c, there is no reason to call `fseek (FP, BufferCount*BufferSize, SEEK_SET);` as your read will continue to move the indicator forward with each read. (you have the same problem with `fseek()` in Reader.c)

Additionally `Buf` is an unused variable in `Reader.c`.

Further, you are not validating the return of `fread (Buf, 1, BufferSize, FP);` or `fwrite (&M->Data[M->ReadPointer * BufferSize], 1, BufferSize, FP);`. While in the case of file operations you should have compete reads and writes of `Buffersize` bytes, that isn't guaranteed so it is necessary to check the return (especially when reading 2-byte blocks with an *odd* (51-byte) input file). There will be a 1-byte read or write somewhere and if you are blindly writing 2-bytes each time, something isn't going to work out.

Which brings us to the crux of your problem writing the complete `bbb.txt` (or writing more bytes than are in `aaa.txt`) using `M->FileEnding` as the shared flag indicating end of input. There is a counting problem here that I will let you sort out. It begins when you buffer `10` (read from file and) writes to `Data` before you begin your reads. Your `Writer.c` counter is `10` ahead of the counter in `Reader.c` before `Reader.c` begins. Which is why on most runs you have `16` iterations of `Reader` when `Writer` sets the  `M->FileEnding` causing `Reader` to write the first 32-bytes of `bbb.txt` and quits. (then on enough runs you will actually write `Buffer Writing: 22` times, or `Buffer Writing: 27` times resulting in a 58-byte `bbb.txt` (with all numbers `1-20` written and then a few stray `0`s at the end).

I provided the link Consider [5 Big Fat Reasons Why Mutexes Suck Big Time](https://accu.org/var/uploads/journals/Overload149.pdf) (2nd Article) to help explain pitfalls surrounding conclusively covering all cases in various paths multi-threaded code can take. Here you have as basic of logic as you can, but there can still be issues in which buffers are filled when and unloaded when and when the `M->FileEnding` flag is set and recognized. Take the time to go back through the logic and ensure that your `FullMutex`, and `FreeMutex` logic is doing what is intended. I don't have a silver-bullet for you there off the top of my head and it will take an iteration-by-iteration debug of what possible combination can be set -- which I leave to you.

Comment: Awesome This is quite helpful.

Comment: Sure, I hope it helps. Sorry I couldn't point to the exact logic error, but that is the inherent difficulty in using mutexes and shared flags between separate processes. It will take just good ole' fashion debugging. If I was doing it, I would sit down with an 8.5x11 sheet of paper and pencil and start with iteration `1)` on the left side and then step through the possible states of the mutexes and flags. I'd do that for each iteration (things will get interesting about iteration `10)`. Then pay careful attention to how the `M->FileEnding` can be set and reacted to in Reader.c. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The MemData has been changed to keep track how many Buffers has been Written or Read.

Here is the Writer.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(void){
    char FileName[128]="aaa.txt";
    struct MemData{
        sem_t FullMutex;
        sem_t FreeMutex;
        int ReadPointer;
        int WritePointer;
        int NumberOfFileBuffers;
        char Data[512000];//MEMORY BLOCK SIZE: 500 KB
    };
    int SD;
    struct MemData *M;
    int NumberOfBuffers=10;
    //int BufferSize=51200;//FILE BUFFER SIZE 50 KB
    int BufferSize=2;//EXPERIMENATION
    unsigned char Buf[BufferSize];
    int BufferCount=0;

    SD= shm_open("/program.shared", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, S_IREAD|S_IWRITE);
    if(SD< 0){
        printf("\nshm_open() error \n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    fchmod(SD, S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO);
    if(ftruncate(SD, sizeof(struct MemData))< 0){
        printf ("ftruncate() error \n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    M=(struct MemData*)mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct MemData), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, SD, 0);
    if(M== MAP_FAILED){
        printf("mmap() error");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }else{
        FILE *FP= fopen(FileName, "rb");
        if(FP!= NULL){
            struct stat StatBuf;
            if(stat(FileName, &StatBuf)==-1){
                printf("failed to fstat %s\n", FileName);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            long long FileSize=StatBuf.st_size;
            printf("\nFile Size: %lld", FileSize);
            long long FilePosition=ftell(FP);
            FilePosition=ftell(FP);
            long long CopyableMemorySize=FileSize-FilePosition;
            printf("\nCopyable File Size: %lld", CopyableMemorySize);
            int NumberOfFileBuffers=ceil(CopyableMemorySize/BufferSize);
            printf("\nNumber Of File Buffers: %d\n", NumberOfFileBuffers);

            //INITIALIZATION
            sem_init(&M->FullMutex, 1, 0);
            sem_init(&M->FreeMutex, 1, NumberOfBuffers);
            M->ReadPointer=0;
            M->WritePointer=0;
            M->NumberOfFileBuffers=NumberOfFileBuffers;
            memset(M->Data, '\0', sizeof(M->Data));

            //WRITE
            while(1){
                sem_wait(&M->FreeMutex);
                fseek(FP, BufferCount*BufferSize, SEEK_SET);
                fread(Buf, sizeof(unsigned char), BufferSize, FP);
                int FreeMutexValue;
                sem_getvalue(&M->FreeMutex, &FreeMutexValue);
                int FullMutexValue;
                sem_getvalue(&M->FullMutex, &FullMutexValue);
                printf("\nMutexes-Free: %d and Full: %d\n", FreeMutexValue, FullMutexValue);
                printf("\nBuffer Writing: %d\n", BufferCount);
                memcpy(&M->Data[M->WritePointer*BufferSize], Buf, BufferSize);
                BufferCount++;
                M->WritePointer=(M->WritePointer+1)%NumberOfBuffers;
                sem_post(&M->FullMutex);                
                if(BufferCount==M->NumberOfFileBuffers){
                    fclose(FP);
                    break;
                }
                //sem_post(&M->FullMutex);                
            }
        }
        close(SD);
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the Reader.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(void){
    char FileName[128]="bbb.txt";
    struct MemData{
        sem_t FullMutex;
        sem_t FreeMutex;
        int ReadPointer;
        int WritePointer;
        int NumberOfFileBuffers;
        char Data[512000];//MEMORY BLOCK SIZE: 500 KB
    };
    int SD;
    struct MemData *M;
    int NumberOfBuffers=10;
    //int BufferSize=51200;//FILE BUFFER SIZE 50 KB
    int BufferSize=2;//EXPERIMENATION
    //unsigned char Buf[BufferSize];
    int BufferCount=0;
    SD= shm_open("/program.shared", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, S_IREAD|S_IWRITE);
    if(SD< 0){
        printf("\nshm_open() error \n"); 
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    M=(struct MemData*)mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct MemData), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, SD, 0);
    if(M== MAP_FAILED){
        printf("mmap() error");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }else{
        FILE *FP= fopen(FileName, "wb");
        if(FP!= NULL){

            //READ
            while(1){
                sem_wait(&M->FullMutex);
                int FreeMutexValue;
                sem_getvalue(&M->FreeMutex, &FreeMutexValue);
                int FullMutexValue;
                sem_getvalue(&M->FullMutex, &FullMutexValue);
                printf("\nMutexes-Free: %d and Full: %d", FreeMutexValue, FullMutexValue);
                printf("\nBuffer Writing: %d", BufferCount);
                printf("\nReadPointer: %d and WritePointer: %d", M->ReadPointer, M->WritePointer);
                printf("\nBuffer Writing: %d\n", BufferCount);
                fseek(FP, BufferCount*BufferSize, SEEK_SET);
                fwrite(&M->Data[M->ReadPointer*BufferSize], sizeof(unsigned char), BufferSize, FP);
                BufferCount++;
                M->ReadPointer=(M->ReadPointer+1)%NumberOfBuffers;
                sem_post(&M->FreeMutex);
                if(BufferCount==M->NumberOfFileBuffers){
                    fclose(FP);
                    break;
                }
                //sem_post(&M->FreeMutex);
            }
        }
        munmap(M,sizeof(struct MemData));
        close(SD);
    }
    return 0;
}
```